# Cohomology class of the diagonal in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

$\newcommand{\cl}{\mathrm{cl}}$Given a projective smooth variety $X$ of dimension $n$ over $\mathbb C$ , and a smooth closed subvariety $Y\subset X$ of codimension $p$, one defines the cohomology class $\cl_Y$ of $Y$, in $H^p(X,\Omega_X^p)$. My question: is there a formula for the cohomology class $\cl_\Delta$ for the diagonal $\Delta\subset X\times X$ ? In particular surfaces and higher dimensions ?

Comment: In what terms do you want such formula to be written?

Comment: I don't know exactly in what terms. There is something, but in de Rham cohomology in  Caramello, O., Lafforgue, L. Cohomology of toposes. Chapter III.https://www.oliviacaramello.com/Teaching/Chapter3.pdf  p.124

Comment: I don't know if this is what you are asking for, but $H^*(X):=\bigoplus_{p,q}H^{p}(X,\Omega ^q)$ is a Weil cohomology. So if $(e_i)$ is a basis of $H^*(X)$ and $(e'_j)$ the dual basis, and $p,q$ are the two projections, $\operatorname{cl}_{\Delta }=\sum \pm \,p^*e_i\cup q^*e'_i $ (the sign depends on the conventions).

Comment: @abx Thank you for this formula.